# Use Compactness Theorem to prove that "an even number of things with property Y" cannot be expressed in first order predicate logic

Tags: logic, compactness, first-order-logic, formal-languages

I am trying to prove that "an even number of things have property Y" cannot be expressed in first order predicate logic. I need to prove this using compactness theorem. I have tried looking online but cannot figure this out as much as I try.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ultraproduct construction?

Comment: @Wore There is no need for ultraproducts here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $\phi_0$ is a sentence that holds in a structure iff $Y(x)$ is true for an even number of values $x$. Now let $\phi_n$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ assert that $Y(x)$ holds for at least $n$ values of $x$. Then any finite subset of $\Phi = \{\phi_0, \phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots\}$ has a model and hence is consistent. By compactness, $\Phi$ has a model, and in this model $Y(x)$ holds for infinitely many $x$. Even numbers are (usually assumed to be) finite, so $\phi_0$ can't be doing its job.

There is a a rationale for defining infinite cardinalities to be even. If you want to do this, then see Noah's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on what, exactly, we mean by "even." Is an infinite set even?

If we say that infinite sets are not even, then Rob's answer is correct.

However, we might also say that an infinite set is both even and odd. In this case, things are a bit trickier. HINT: suppose $\varphi$ says "There are an even number of objects." Then $\neg\varphi$ has arbitrarily large finite models, so by compactness it has an *infinite* model $\mathcal{A}\models\neg\varphi$. But we said above that infinity is both even and odd, so we must have $\mathcal{A}\models\varphi$; and this is a contradiction.

Comment: I dont uderstand your reasoning. After all, $\neg \phi$ states that `There are an odd number of objects` so the situation is symmetric as in case even number. Moreover, I don't understand how can you use here compactness theorem.

Comment: @HaskellFun (I presume you are referring to my alternate solution in the last paragraph.) We apply compactness to the theory $\Gamma=\neg\varphi \cup\{\psi_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $\psi_n$ is the standard sentence "there are at least $n$ elements". Any finite subtheory of $\Gamma$ is clearly consistent, since there are arbitrarily large odd numbers. So by compactness, $\Gamma$ is consistent. But any model $M$ of $\Gamma$ is infinite, hence - since we're considering infinite sets to be even - is a model of $\varphi$. But then $M$ satisfies both $\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$, a contradiction.